# NumberPicker displaying with dark background on Theme.AppCompat.Light

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have applied Theme.AppCompat.Light to my app. All UI components are displayed with the light theme except number picker(including date/time pickers). The result is below. The axml code is below as well. How do i get number picker with the light theme.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <NumberPicker
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/agePicker" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: check your style you have applied `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light` not `Appcompat`.

Comment: Post your style.xml

Comment: changing theme to 
    @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light
 has the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `Theme.AppCompat.Light` instead of `Theme.Holo.Light`

#### Via Manifest:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"></application>
```

#### Via Manifest Property Editor:

[image]

#### Activity Level `Theme.AppCompat.Light`:

```
[Activity(Label = "AppCompatLight", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light")]
public class MainActivity : ActionBarActivity
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Activity Level `Theme.Holo.Light`:

```
[Activity(Label = "ThemeLight", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light")]
```

Application Level `Theme.Holo.Light`:

#### Via Manifest:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"></application>
```

#### Via Manifest Property Editor:

[image]

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: I have tried your suggestions, no luck. Still seeing the same behavior

Comment: @darkphantum What version of `Xamarin.Android` are you using? Also what Nuget version of `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` is in your project?

Comment: Xamarin.Android v6.1 and nuget version of AppCompat library is 23.4